# How to set numbering so it's section > subsection > paragraph

Tags: numbering

I'm literally just learning LaTeX and after going around in circles for an hour I thought it would be easier to just ask.

I'm trying to format a report as follows:

`1. First Section
    1.1 Subsection Title
        1.1.1 This is paragraph one
        1.1.2 This is paragraph two`

`2. Second Section
    2.1 Subsection Title
        2.1.1 This is paragraph three
        2.1.2 This is paragraph four`

Ideally I'd like to define a simple "tag" (I'm sorry, I don't know the proper terminology) so that it would look as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{My Document Title}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\mycustomtag This is paragraph one
\mycustomtag This is paragraph two

\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\mycustomtag This is paragraph three
\mycustomtag This is paragraph four

\end{document}
```

Is this possible? (Ideally in such a way that the section and subsections would still work in a table of contents?). I found ways of numbering paragraphs but because I'm not using subsubsections the numbers become 1.1.0.1 etc which I'd rather avoid.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: it is simper (and better) to use `\subsubsection` and just specify that subsubsections are formatted as you want (eg like the existing `\paragraph`)

Comment: Use \subsubsection as it is the correct command, if you don't like its look you can adapt it.

Comment: Next question then: How does one change the formatting of the `\subsubsection`? :)

Comment: This would be another question. You should not ask questions in comments but click to "Ask Question" for new questions. But in this case you should know, that we already have [questions about formatting of headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sectioning+formatting?sort=votes&pageSize=15). You should have a look at those.

Comment: You should take a look at `titlesec` package, which is done precisely for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a subsubsection working like a paragraph you need to change a value in its definition. The original definition is in article.cls:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {-1em}% <---changed
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{blub}
\subsection{bblb} blblb
\subsubsection{blbl}blblb
\paragraph{blbl}  bblbl
\end{document}
```

You can also use the `titlesec` package. Or you can use the class `scrartcl` (part of the KOMA-bundle) instead of `article`, KOMA has its own system to adapt the heading commands.